# Meteor method not returning return value when return wrapped in a callback

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am having trouble getting a server Meteor.method to return a successful response when I wrap the return in a callback.

It works fine when not wrapped in a call back.

It can throw new Meteor.errors both when wrapped in a call back and when not wrapped in a call back.

Wrapping the Meteor.call on the client side in this exact same fashion works fine.

But, for some reason doing this on the server does not return a response value when return is called.

Here is an example.  This is not my exact code but very close.  It is very close though.

```
Meteor.methods({
  insertData: insertData
});

function insertData(params){
 validateParams(params, function(bool, msg){
  if(bool){
    //do stuff, like insert records
    result = 'thanks a million gagillions';
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  } else {
    throw new Meteor.Error(513, msg);
  }
 });
}

validateParams(params, callback){
  for (var key in params) {
    value = params[key];
    if(_.isEmpty(value) || _.isUndefined(value) || _.isNull(value)) {
      callback(false, 'Please enter your "'+ key + '".'); 
      return;
    }
  }
  callback(true);
}
```

How do I get this to work so that the result is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need callbacks here.  You might find the straight-line code more readable.

```
Meteor.methods({
  insertData: insertData
});

function insertData(params){
  // run validator, allow exception to propagate
  validateParams(params);

  //do stuff, like insert records
  result = 'thanks a million gagillions';
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

function validateParams(params){
  for (var key in params) {
    value = params[key];
    if(_.isEmpty(value) || _.isUndefined(value) || _.isNull(value))
      throw new Meteor.Error('Please enter your "'+ key + '".');
  }
  // not strictly necessary, just don't throw exception.
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This worked great.  Tip to others.  If you  call a shared function that throws a new Meteor.Error from the client side, wrap it in a try catch.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the return statement belongs to the function you pass to `validateParams`. It does not belong to the `insertData` function.

You can see this better if you split the code sections:

```
function insertFunc(bool, msg) {
  // do your work
  return result;
}

function insertData(params) {
  validateParams(params, insertFunc);
  // no return statement..
}
```

You need to propagate the return value of the callback in `validateParams`:

```
validateParams(params, callback){
  for (var key in params) {
    value = params[key];
    if(_.isEmpty(value) || _.isUndefined(value) || _.isNull(value)) {
      return callback(false, 'Please enter your "'+ key + '".');  // <----- here
    }
  }
  return callback(true); // <---- and here
}
```

and then return the result of `validateParams` in your function:

```
function insertData(params){
  return validateParams(params, function(bool, msg) {
    // your code..
  });
}
```

Note: Throwing exceptions work because these are propagated until a try/catch block is reached.

Comment: This also works to solve the solution for someone that wants to use callbacks.